# Discord.py: Access files on the computer of the person who sent a message. Play a song from the local drive of any user on the server

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord.py

I have a bot that can play music from my computer. Is there a way to play a song from the computer of the person who sent the message? My thought would be using `message.author` to somehow access the person's session and get into their drive. Here is my bot. It can join a voice channel, create playlists from local file paths, start a playlist or individual file with stop/pause/play/next/previous controls:

```
import discord
import os.path
import logging
import asyncio
from os import path

global ready 
global vc
global source
global songQueue
global songIndex
global commandList
global stopPlaylist

ready = False
stopPlaylist = False
songQueue = []
songIndex = 0

logger = logging.getLogger('discord')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.FileHandler(filename='D:\DnD\DiscordBot\discord.log', encoding='utf-8', mode='w')
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

client = discord.Client()
commands = [
    '!connect\nConnect to a voice channel by channel id. Use !channels to find the desired id.\nExample Command: !connect 827202170973323305\n\n',
    '!channels\nLists all voice channels and their connection id.\n\n',
    '!add\nAdd a file path to the playlist.\nExample Command: !add D:\\DnD\\DiscordBot\\mySong.mp3\n\n',
    '!delete\nDeletes the last song added to the playlist.\n\n',
    '!view\nDisplays the current playlist, in order.\n\n',
    '!playlist\nStarts the playlist from the beginning, or optionally add a number as the start position.\nExample Command: !playlist 3\n\n',
    '!playSong\nPlays a specified file.\nExample Command: !playSong D:\\DnD\\DiscordBot\\mySong.mp3\n\n',
    '!next\nPlays next song in playlist.\n\n',
    '!prev\nPlays previous song in playlist.\n\n',
    '!stop\nStops all music song. Playlist will restart from the beginning.\n\n',
    '!pause\nPauses the current song. Restart with !resumeSong.\n\n',
    '!resume\nResumes the current song.\n\n'
    '!status\nLets you know if the bot thinks it is playing music.'
    ]
commandList=''
for command in commands:
    commandList+=command

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global ready 
    global vc
    global source
    global songQueue
    global songIndex
    global commandList
    global stopPlaylist

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
#!help
    if message.content.startswith('!help'):
        await message.channel.send('{0}'.format(commandList))
        return
#!connect
    if message.content.startswith('!connect'):  
        if ready:
            await message.channel.send('Bot [{0}] is already connected to a voice channel.'.format(client.user))
            return
        channel = int(message.content[9:])
        vc = await client.get_channel(channel).connect()
        ready = True
        await message.channel.send('Bot [{0}] is connecting to voice.'.format(client.user))
        return
#!channels
    if message.content.startswith('!channels'):
        channelList = ''
        for channel in client.get_all_channels():
            if channel.type == discord.ChannelType.voice:
                channelList += 'name: ' + channel.name + '\n'
                channelList += 'id: ' + str(channel.id) + '\n\n'
        await message.channel.send('{0}'.format(channelList))
        return
#!add
    if message.content.startswith('!add'):
        song = message.content[5:]
        if not path.exists(song):
            await message.channel.send('Song not found or invalid path specified.\nSpecified Path: {0}\nExample command: !addSong C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\mySong.mp3'.format(song))
            return
        songQueue.append(song)
        await message.channel.send('Song added: {0}\nCurrent playist length: {1} song(s)'.format(song,len(songQueue)))
        return
#!delete
    if message.content.startswith('!delete'):
        if len(songQueue) == 0:
            await message.channel.send('Playlist is empty. Use !addSong, !viewList, and !playList to manage playlists.')
            return
        await message.channel.send('Removed song: {0}'.format(songQueue.pop()))
        return
#!view
    if message.content.startswith('!view'):
        if len(songQueue) == 0:
            await message.channel.send('Playlist is empty. Use !addSong, !deleteSong, and !playList to manage playlists.')
            return
        await message.channel.send('Current Playlist:\n{0}'.format('\n'.join(songQueue)))
        return
#play commands
    if message.content.startswith('!play'):
        if not ready:
            await message.channel.send('Bot [{0}] is not connected to a voice channel.'.format(client.user))
            return
#!playlist  
        if message.content.startswith('!playlist'):
            try:
                songIndex = int(message.content[10:]) - 1
                if songIndex >= len(songQueue):
                    songIndex = len(songQueue) - 1
            except:
                pass    
            playSong()
            return
#!playSong
        if message.content.startswith('!playSong'):
            song = message.content[10:]
            if not path.exists(song):
                await message.channel.send('Song not found or invalid path specified.\nSpecified Path: {0}\nExample command: !play C:\\Users\\Public\\Music\\mySong.mp3'.format(song))
                return
            source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song)
            vc.play(source, after=None)
            await message.channel.send('Playing song: {0}'.format(song))
            return
#!next
    if message.content.startswith('!next'):
        vc.stop()
#!prev
    if message.content.startswith('!prev'):
        songIndex -= 2
        if songIndex < -1:
            songIndex = -1
        vc.stop()
#!stop
    if message.content.startswith('!stop'):
        if not ready:
            await message.channel.send('Bot [{0}] is not connected to a voice channel.'.format(client.user))
            return
        vc.stop()
        songIndex = 0
        stopPlaylist = True
        await message.channel.send('Stopping music.')
        return
#!pause
    if message.content.startswith('!pause'):
        if not ready:
            await message.channel.send('Bot [{0}] is not connected to a voice channel.'.format(client.user))
            return
        vc.pause()
        await message.channel.send('Pausing music.')
        return
#!resume
    if message.content.startswith('!resume'):
        if not ready:
            await message.channel.send('Bot [{0}] is not connected to a voice channel.'.format(client.user))
            return
        vc.resume()
        await message.channel.send('Resuming music.')
        return
#!status
    if message.content.startswith('!status'):
        if not ready:
            await message.channel.send('Bot [{0}] is not connected to a voice channel.'.format(client.user))
            return
        if vc.is_playing():
            await message.channel.send('Something is playing.')
            return
        await message.channel.send('Nothing is playing.')
        return

def playSong():
    global songQueue
    global songIndex
    global vc
    try:
        song = songQueue[songIndex]
        source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song)
        vc.play(source, after=nextSong)
    except Exception as e:
        print('playSong error {0}'.format(e))

def nextSong(error):
    global songQueue
    global songIndex
    global stopPlaylist
    try:
        songIndex += 1
        if songIndex >= len(songQueue):
            stopPlaylist = True
        if stopPlaylist:
            songIndex = 0
            stopPlaylist = False
            return
        futureFunction = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(playSong(), client.loop)
        futureFunction.result()
    except Exception as e:
        print('nextSong error {0}'.format(e))

#@client.event
#async def on_logout(user)
#   global ready
#   if user == client.user:
#       ready = False

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Let's reframe this - would you be at all concerned if any arbitrary Discord bot on any server you joined could rifle through the files on your drives? (I would.) I don't think what you're describing is possible, and for *good reason*.

Comment: In any case - Stack Overflow won't write your code *for* you. Instead, edit your question to illustrate what you've specifically tried at a code level to meet the requirement you describe, along with a succinct summary of why this attempt didn't meet your requirements (being sure to include all pertinent error messages, expected vs. actual behaviors, etc.) in accordance with the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the thing you must know is that you can access your local drive cause the bot runs on it, but of course you can't access other users drive (it will be very dangerous). Neither discord.py and Discord allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I guess I just don't see the point of the bot as a music device if multiple users can't supply music for it. That's the crux of the question I'm asking.